# Query for two different scenarios

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to write a query which acheives the following requirements

```
1.) Need to get one row for the combination of "PrimaryID1" and "PrimaryID2", there are more than one field for this combination.
2.) There are two sub conditions here we need to take in to account.
    2.a) For fields with "FlagField = 1"
         In some combination of "PrimaryID1" and "PrimaryID2" we have "FlagField = 1" in this case  only that particular field needs to be taken
    2.b) For fields with "FlagField IS NULL"
         If "FlagField IS NULL" then the requirement is like we need to pull the record for min of "PrimaryID3"(its a diff. field)
```

Here is how the data looks like

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PrimaryID1       PrimaryID2       PrimaryID3       FlagField       DataField1       DataField2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PPID11             PPID21           1                  0             DF111            DF211
PPID11             PPID21           2                  1             DF112            DF212
PPID11             PPID21           3                  0             DF113            DF213

PPID12             PPID22           1                 NULL           DF121            DF221
PPID12             PPID22           2                 NULL           DF122            DF222
PPID12             PPID22           3                 NULL           DF123            DF223
```

Sample result

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PrimaryID1       PrimaryID2       PrimaryID3       FlagField       DataField1       DataField2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PPID11             PPID21           2                  1             DF112            DF212

PPID12             PPID22           1                 NULL           DF121            DF221
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample results.

Comment: what's your query so far?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry !! I missed out one field "PrimaryID3" now its been added !! Also sample result is added !!

Comment: @WimOmbelets the data that i have shown here is the source from which i need to query and the end result should only have the "second row" and the "Fourth row" based upon the condition that i have already specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to identify the row with the lowest PrimaryID3. Wrapping that in a case statement will allow you to 'conditionally combine' it with the FlagField. You then just need to filter on the result of the expression.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, r = CASE WHEN FlagField IS NOT NULL THEN FlagField ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PrimaryID1, PrimaryID2 ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(PrimaryID3, 'PPID', '') AS INT)) END
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE r = 1
```

Comment: Sorry !! I edited the "PrimaryID3" field, but still any how your idea seems good !! i will implement that !! Thanks a lot !!